# How to write Mozilla specific CSS using withStyles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mozilla, css-in-js

I am developing a React application and using `withStyles` CSS in JS library for handling CSS. I am facing an issue in Mozilla where I have to change height attribute as per Mozilla browser. How can I change it using CSS in JS? Seems `@-moz-document url-prefix()` does not work in withStyles.

```
const styles = theme => ({
    radioGroupRoot : {
        backgroundColor : "#fff9d8",
        alignItems : "center",
        marginTop : '15px'
    },
    labelRoot : {
        margin : 0,
        width : "100%",
        alignItems : "end"
    },
    radioLabel : {
        width : "100%",
        backgroundColor: "#fff9d8"
    },
    radioRoot : {
        height : "37px",
        width : "37px",
        color : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)'
    },
    '@-moz-document url-prefix()' : { 
        radioRoot : {
            height: '52px'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you asked if anyone has a direct fix for your issue instead of adding browser specific code?

Comment: @Kravimir Sorry I didn't get it ...  Even for Direct fix I need to identify that browser is Mozilla and not chrome and so I can modify my CSS accordingly ..

Comment: Sorry my point wasn't clear. I'm asking if you've asked for help finding a workaround for the browser difference without using browser specific code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The @-moz-document CSS at-rule has been disabled with Firefox 61 to mitigate the risk of CSS injection attacks
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1449753

try with

```
@supports ( -moz-appearance:none ){
  /* Add firefox CSS code here */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  But is it the best way to do it?

Comment: depends on the compatibility you are looking for
[@supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports#Browser_compatibility)